# SQL - Use of two conditions or more in select with AND

Tags: sql

I can not get data I want according to two conditions and i have this DATABASE:

```
Theatre(t_name, city, sinceYear);
Actor(a_id, a_name, birthYear, city);
Play(p_id, title, playwright, director, year);
Role(a_id, p_id, role, t_name);

Theatre:
Abima|tel aviv|1/1/1960
Miskan|beer sheba|20/2/1970
Akamri|haifa|15/3/1989

Actor:
204458952|Dani|22/1/1993|sderot
221354875|Osher|23/8/1995|beer sheba
251445841|Avi|5/12/1998|haifa
304226152|Noa|12/5/1992|tel avia
304804123|Shir|10/6/1990|beer sheba

Play:
111|Meri lo|Lior|Hanoh levin|2010
222|Tov agmad|Asaf|Nisim Aloni|2016
333|Songs|Ami|Hanoh levin|2018
444|Run it|Sami|Nisim Aloni|2010

Role:
304804123|111|meri|Abima
304226152|111|sonia|Abima
251445841|222|tov tov|Miskan
204458952|222|gamad |Abima
221354875|333|prince|Akamri
304804123|222|princes|Abima
```

I want to receive all the actors who appeared in Hanoh levin Play and did not appear in Nisim Aloni Play (In the present case get them all except from shir.

i try to do this:

```
  SELECT a_id, a_name FROM (
     Select * FROM Actor JOIN Play, Role ON Actor.a_id=Role.a_id AND 
     Role.p_id=Play.p_id WHERE  
        director='Hanoh levin') AND NOT EXISTS (
          Select * FROM Actor JOIN Play, Role ON Actor.a_id=Role.a_id AND 
             Role.p_id=Play.p_id WHERE  
                director='Nisim Aloni');
```

I get an error or I do not get anything if I change it a bit. 
According to the database I should not accept the actress Shir because she appears in the plays of two directors.
what i do wrong?

thank's

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following query with joins :

```
select a_name
  from Actor a
  join Role r on r.a_id = a.a_id
  join Play p on p.p_id = r.p_id 
 where exists ( select 1 from Play where director = 'Hanoh levin' and p_id = p.p_id )
   and not exists ( select 1 from Play where director = 'Nisim Aloni' and p_id = p.p_id );

A_NAME
------
Shir
Noa
Osher
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://rextester.com/NWBA15697)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Join 3 tables and group by actor's name:

```
select a.a_name 
from actor a inner join role r
on r.a_id = a.a_id
inner join play p
on p.p_id = r.p_id
where p.director in ('Hanoh levin', 'Nisim Aloni')
group by a.a_name
having min(p.director) = 'Hanoh levin' and max(p.director) = 'Hanoh levin'
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8SqDTgkRFGfsPgDg3ZkQ2B/1)
Results:

```
| a_name |
| ------ |
| Noa    |
| Osher  |
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply check against director.

```
select a_name from Actor a
  join Role r on r.a_id = a.a_id
  join Play p on p.p_id = r.p_id 
 where  p.director = 'Hanoh levin' 
   and p.director <> 'Nisim Aloni'
```